# jQuery fadeIn not displaying

Tags: jquery, css, html

Despite the fact that my classes are correct, and JQuery is working properly, I am still having trouble using the `fadeIN` property on my `jumbotron` element. Any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.not_displaying').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('not_displaying');
});
```

```css
div.not_displaying {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div style="background:transparent !important" class="jumbotron text-center not_displaying">
    <img id="jumbotron_img" src="images/Enriceo.png">
    <h3 class="container-fluid" id="presentation"> trial</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to remove the class

Comment: mmm, still not working tho :(

Comment: Just use `$('.jumbotron').fadeIn(1000);` no need to hide, no need to remove class.

Comment: It works for me can you explain a little bit more

Comment: Now it works :). Basically the default link to the Jquery library provided by Bootstrap4 template file did not work properly. I substituted the script with the one provided in the edited code by Pedram and now everything works fine.